# Can I choose a subset of ordered effects when doing multiple hypothesis testing?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, genetics

I have a question about multiple hypothesis testing.

Suppose I calculate an effect for 2000 gene on some outcome. I order those effects, and only take the top 10 genes according to effect. I **only check these 10 values** against the null distribution to get pvalues. Then I correct those pvalues according to 10 hypotheses, not 2000. Is it unfair that I chose those 10 genes by ordering the 2000 effects first?

Comment: On the one hand, I have seen the data to order the effect sizes, but on the other hand, I have not observed the remaining 1990 gene's relationships to the null distribution.

Comment: And so maybe we can start with a simpler question, can anyone point me to an explicit definition of when I have checked multiple hypotheses? Is it a weaker definition that I observed the effect, or is it a stronger definition that I checked the pvalue of the effect?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds fishy, to say the least ... standard for genetics studys today seems to be using **false discovery rates**, see my answer at [statistical analysis - without data dredging](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226386/statistical-analysis-without-data-dredging/226738#226738)  and the links/references there.